# how to try error in jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
 setTimeout(function() { 
        window.location.href = $(".user a")[0].href; 
     }, 2000);
});
```

i put the above jquery code in a js file.which invoked by the site's header template.but in some pages(there is no `.user a`) shows an error "`0.href is null or not an object` on IE status bar. how to prevent the error shows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check whwther there are any elements on the page which match the selector `.user a`, before trying to read from the first one:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 setTimeout(function() {  
        if($(".user a").length)
        {
            window.location.href = $(".user a")[0].href; 
        }
     }, 2000);
});
```

As mentioned elsewhere, it might be a good idea to change that line also to:

```
window.location.href = $(".user a").eq(0).attr("href");
```

Comment: Also you should use .attr("href") instead of just .href.

Comment: @niaher - cant do that unless you use `eq(0)` to get a jQuery object. Accessing the array gets you an HTMLElement

Comment: @El Ronnoco - true, but if reading an attribute is causing a bottleneck you've got bigger problems :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 setTimeout(function() { 
        if ($(".user a").length > 0)
            window.location.href = $(".user a")[0].href; 
     }, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        setTimeout(function() {        
        try {
           window.location.href = $(".user a")[0].href;
           } catch (e) {    
           alert('error so no redirect');   
    }
     }, 2000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/

as pointer out by @Jamiec, you may do `$(".user a").length` and check that element exists or not. I have suggested this way (tray catch), as you questions title says so.

Comment: Not a good idea, since there is a known scenario where no ".user a" object exists on the page - hence it is not an "exceptional" situation. Moreover, there is an easy workaround for that - check the length of result array (as proposed in other answers to this thrad)

Comment: Its still a bad answer. Consider a different analogy. Say I ask "How do I bang in a nail with my shoe?".. there is a literal answer, but it's the wrong one (answer: don't use a shoe, use a hammer). In this case, the answer is "dont use try..catch, first check whether the element you are trying to read is available".

Comment: @jamie: okie, i got ur point, and i think ur correct. Also if is faster than try catch http://jsperf.com/try-catch-vs-if34

Answer (score -1):

you need to use jQuery attributes to prevent cross browser differences

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     setTimeout(function() { 
            window.location.href = $(".user a").eq(0).attr('href'); 
         }, 2000);
    });
```

Comment: Please leave comments when downvoting!!! People aren't going to learn if you don't say *why* this is a poor solution.

Comment: you are talking to me ? I didn't downvoting someone here, I just upvoting jamaic because its answer was the right one. As contrary I red the question two quickly and gave a bad answer...

Comment: You misunderstand - Someone downvoted *you*! But they left no explanation as to why they thought your answer was poor. My comment is addressed to the downvoter, not to you! (I have a problem with people who "downvote and run"!) :)